# Visualize multi attribute data in a 2D plane

Tags: java, gnuplot, visualization, k-means

I have a dataset having 32 attributes. I am applying K-Means clustering on the dataset to find out the clusters. Now I want to visualize the data points.

The challenge in visualization of these points is we have to convert this multidimensional data to a 2-dimensional data and then give this data to any java visualization library.

I tried applying Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to the data to get a 2 dimensional reduction. Then used java-gnuplot library to visualize the data. But the result was not accurate.

Is there any java library that automatically converts n-dimensional data to a 2 dimensional data and visualize the data points?

Comment: This is usually referred to as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction and ... one of the things that data scientists get the big bucks for...